# Am I receiving a false error where the solution is terminal based or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend, bundle, navigation-drawer

The error is saying that it cannot find './Menu/SettingScreen' from './Menu/DrawerNavigation' saying it doesn't exist. But I have removed the SettingScreen file from App.js and DrawerNavigation but I'm still getting the exact error

In short, I tried removing the file but the error stays the same. Can someone please help? Below I will show the DrawerNavigation code without the presence of the SettingScreen file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import Map from './Menu/Map'

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerConfig = {
    drawerWidth: WIDTH*0.83,
};





const menuDrawerNavigator= createDrawerNavigator ({

Home:{ screen: Map

},


},
DrawerConfig

);

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

Comment: This kind of error might be misleading. Make sure your IDE shows correct files. Check if files exists or not from terminal. Terminal is always correct :)

Comment: Did you try to restart your terminal?

Comment: Try to rebuild and run it again.

Comment: Hey yes, I did restart my terminal a few times still the same results. I have checked with my terminal for these files and others and it doesn't find them. It's strange because it was working well then all broke down once I tried importing a file to App.js and then even when I remove it, the error persists. Is there any way to approach this?